# Cのprintfでの$(ドルマーク)の意味

Tags: c, security

よくCTFなどで書式化文字列攻撃をするときに`%4$x`というような文字列をprintfで渡したりしますが、この書式化文字列でのドルマークの意味はどういったものでしょうか?

書式文字列攻撃について解説したこのページでも出てきています

[書式指定文字列攻撃](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/kusano_k/20140302/1393781714)

> "%n$x"という表記によって、n+1番目の引数があるべき位置の値を表示することもできる。これでスタックの先の方も覗けるし、何番目の書式指定文字か気にする必要が無くなる。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[POSIX仕様](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html)です。`%4$x`は可変引数の４番目の引数を参照することを指示します。

> これでスタックの先の方も覗けるし、何番目の書式指定文字か気にする必要が無くなる。

は脆弱な環境での話で、POSIX仕様上は

> When numbered argument specifications are used, specifying the Nth argument requires that all the leading arguments, from the first to the (N-1)th, are specified in the format string.

と指摘されています。そもそもC言語の可変引数では各引数が何バイトになるか不明なため、`(N-1)th`までの引数が使われていないことには`Nth`の正確なアドレスは決定できません。（K&R C仕様から不明な引数は`int`と見なすべき…という考え方もできなくはない？）

---

ちなみにVisual C++ですが、`$`形式はPOSIX仕様でありC言語仕様ではないため、`printf`系関数はこの機能をサポートしていません。ただし、全く使えないわけではなく、[全ての`printf`系関数に対応する`printf_p`関数](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/c-runtime-library/printf-p-positional-parameters?view=msvc-160)が用意されていて、こちらのバージョンを使用することで`$`形式を使用できます。

Answer (score 3):

適切な回答がついていますので蛇足です。長くなったのでコメントでなく回答としておきます。

`$` は posix による拡張なので [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) では定義されていません。そのため非 posix な環境、たとえば Visual C とか組み込み系コンパイラ（の stdio ライブラリ）では `$` をサポートしていません。

提示リンク先にある `%n` のほうは標準です（ [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) に記載あり）。
ですが安全性確保のため Visual C ではデフォルト状態では使えないようになっています。
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx
同様 [c11](/questions/tagged/c11) では `%n` を削除した `printf_s` が追加されています。互換性確保のため `printf` から `%n` を削除することはできなかったらしい。
https://www.buildinsider.net/language/clang/02